# Updating a View

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below view and I am trying to update the view. The error : "virtual column not allowed here" is being displayed. How can I arrange this?

Thanks
Keith Spiteri

View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW FilmDetailsView
   (Film_Name, Actor_FullName, Hall_Number, Date_Time)
AS SELECT flm.film_name, actor.actor_name || ' ' || actor.actor_surname, 
   hall.cinemahall_number, schedule.schedule_date
FROM film flm 
JOIN movieschedule schedule
ON (flm.film_id = schedule.schedule_filmid)
JOIN cinemahall hall
ON (schedule.schedule_hallid = hall.cinemahall_id)
JOIN FilmActor filmactor
ON (flm.film_id = filmactor.filmactor_filmid)
JOIN Actor actor
ON (actor.actor_id = filmactor.filmactor_actorid);
```

The Update:

```
UPDATE FILMDETAILSVIEW
SET ACTOR_FULLNAME = 'a'
WHERE HALL_NUMBER = 1;
```

The Error:

```
Error starting at line 312 in command:
UPDATE FILMDETAILSVIEW
SET ACTOR_FULLNAME = 'a'
WHERE HALL_NUMBER = 1
Error at Command Line:313 Column:4
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here
01733. 00000 -  "virtual column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Where do you expect Oracle to store the data?

Comment: @Álvaro - +1 - perhaps the expectation is that Oracle will "magically pull the full name apart"...  :)

Comment: it can be hall_number.. still does not work

Comment: Because the view contains a virtual column (and other reasons as well) Oracle will not allow updates to the view unless an INSTEAD OF trigger is associated with it. It does not matter what columns you try to update - you'll get an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A view is just a stored query -- when you update through it, it's the underlying tables that must be modified.  How can you update a view column that is generated through a combination of multiple base columns?

The ACTOR_FULLNAME column in the view is a concatenation of two base columns and a literal.  Oracle has no way of knowing what you mean by updating that column.  Should it change ACTOR.ACTOR_NAME, ACTOR.ACTOR_SURNAME, or both?  And how can it update either or both in a way that will behave correctly after the update, given that the expression for the virtual column always includes a space?

If you have some meaningful logic you want to implement to handle such an UPDATE, you could use an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view to implement it.

Comment: no need of trigger. I'm following the notes and there is no trigger when updating view.

Comment: On this particular one, you'll need the instead-of trigger so that it can tell Oracle what you want to have happen when data is inserted/updated to that column. I don't see any other way around it (short of splitting the virtual column up).

Answer (score 5):

Your view contains a virtual column Actor_FullName, which is a concatenation of two other real columns.

You can only update views that meet certain criteria, or have an associated INSTEAD OF trigger. Read more about this at [PSOUG.org.](http://psoug.org/reference/instead_of_trigger.html)

Comment: Doesn't matter what columns you try to update, the view contains the virtual column and is not updatable as written. You will need an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view to update it.

Comment: no need of trigger. I'm following the notes and there is no trigger when updating view.

Comment: @DCookie -- your statement doesn't seem to be true.  Using a base table with three number columns (x,y,z), I created a view as `select x, y+z sum from the_table`.  I was then able to update the `x` column in the view, while attempting to update `sum` gave the virtual-column error.  This is in Oracle 10.2.

Comment: @Mark -- when you try to update `hall_number`, do you get the same error, or a different error (perhaps one saying that the table is not key-preserved)?

Comment: @Dave, you're right, a different message results if you try to update x when joins are involved. The view as written is not updateable, however.

Comment: You can see which columns in a view meet the criteria for being updated through user_updatable_columns

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update a view like you would a table.  That is not possible--you need to instead change the definition of the view.  I've never used Oracle, but in SQL Server, you would use a case statement like so:

```
case hall.cinemahall_number when 1 then 'a'
     else actor.actor_name + ' ' + actor.actor_surname
end as actor_fullname
```

That would go in the definition of your view, where you have

```
actor.actor_name || ' ' || actor.actor_surname
```

right now. (Obviously convert what I wrote to PL/SQL).